# Is there a difference between "leading edge" and "bleeding edge"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns, word-usage

It seems to me that "leading edge" is the more established phrase, while "bleeding edge" is basically the same thing but the user has adapted the phrase for extra (rather meaningless) emphasis.

Or is there a meaningful distinction between the two?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is, in fact, a distinction.

*Leading edge* in this sense, means *[cutting edge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cutting+edge)*.  It refers to the most highly sophisticated development in a field.  However, it rarely or never has the connotation of risky or untested.  It is almost always used to describe the *best*; not necessarily the *newest*.

*[Bleeding edge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bleeding+edge)* would refer to a development that is so new that it could have a high risk of being unreliable and may incur greater expense in order to use it:

> **[Bleeding edge:](http://www.answers.com/topic/bleeding-edge)** A pun on "leading edge." It implies that using the latest technology is often risky because it has not been tested with enough users and may not perform as expected. Introducing an advanced product or service is also risky because the user community may not be ready for it or really want it.

Comment: So "leading edge" technology is similar but less risky? Is the level of risk quantifiable?

Comment: IMHO *leading edge* or *cutting edge* wouldn't be used of a risky development.

Comment: I just did, hence the upvote. :)

Comment: +1 I'd never heard *bleeding edge* before. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: From a medical viewpoint, there is a slight delay in the start of bleeding after a cut, and so bleeding starts at a point _after_ the cutting edge has moved on (possibly cutting deeper).  In that sense, bleeding edge as something even more advanced than leading edge is somewhat of a misnomer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: maybe true, but irrelevant. It is not the EDGE that is moving in this metaphor, but YOU. The relevant saying is, "When you're working at the cutting edge, the trick is to stay behind the blade."

Answer (score 9):

There is a slight semantic difference here.

*Leading edge* refers to people or things who are the foremost or the best in a technology, science, art, skill, etc.

*Bleeding edge* also refers to this fact of being in the foremost, but the difference between *bleeding edge* and *leading edge*, is that *bleeding edge* is **risky**. *Leading edge* is not risky. *Bleeding edge* is.  For example:

> [Bleeding edge technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding_edge_technology) refers to technology that is so new that it could have a high risk of being unreliable and may incur greater expense in order to use it.

[PC Encyclopedia](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,2542,t=bleeding+edge&i=38752,00.asp) defines *bleeding edge*:

> A pun on "leading edge." It implies that using the latest technology is often risky because it has not been tested with enough users and may not perform as expected. Introducing an advanced product or service is also risky because the user community may not be ready for it or really want it

Note how it's derived from *leading edge*.

Comment: "Bleeding edge" is a pun which combines the sound of "leading edge" and the knife metaphor of "cutting edge". The fundamental idea is that it's just a bit beyond the cutting edge.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke once wrote that the only way to discover the limits of the possible was to go a little way beyond them into the impossible. The bleeding edge is a little way beyond the limit.

Comment: @Tom I think you should post an answer, because you are more right than these other answers.

Comment: @Kit: I think this answer is essentially correct. I believe it's better to buttress an essentially correct answer with a comment than to post yet another answer, even if it is slightly more correct. And here, the difference between what Thursagen and i are saying is so small as to fall well within the realm of personal opinion.

Comment: @TomAnderson "The fundamental idea is that it's just a bit beyond the cutting edge."  Actually, bleeding starts _after_ the cutting edge has gone past (and usually deeper).  Thus in actuality it is the cutting edge that is just a bit beyond the bleeding edge, while the usage is taken to mean exactly the opposite.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: It is indeed not a perfectly accurate metaphor! No time for perfect accuracy at the bleeding edge!

Answer (score 0):

*Leading edge* is a term for being in the forefront of a field. The term probably comes from the leading edge of an airfoil or similar body in aerodynamics. *Bleeding edge* is a play on *leading edge*, referring to the high risk of leading edge technology failing or encountering problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of social change rather than technology, "leading edge" concepts are widely accepted, with proponents receiving accolades. While "bleeding edge" concepts are not yet so widely accepted and proponents bleed, metaphorically, as a result, even if the concept is adopted and becomes leading edge at a later date.
Thus, a very big difference between leading edge and bleeding edge.

Answer (score -3):

**Bleeding edge** as others have said is very high risk, mostly is rolled out in commercially unstable environments.

**Leading edge** is industry leading, but risk is reduced and adoption is starting to pick up.

**Trailing edge** technologies simply support the leading edge.

As per the article below, it seems that these patterns are presented as S-Curves in patterns of nature as well as technological, cultural and scientific paradigm shifts.

[image: S-Curves - What can we Learn from Elon Musk]

Source - [What can we learn from Elon Musk](https://www.perchingtree.com/what-can-we-learn-from-elon-musk-about-s-curves/)

Comment: Hi TechBuff2021. Are you affiliated with the site you're linking to? If so, please disclose the affiliation. [How Not To Be A Spammer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)