# A word or a phrase for "completely optimised, thoroughly researched technology"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that can be used in the sentence:

> It is a rather old, but _________________ technology.

The word or phrase should address a technology that is totally investigated, researched in detail, and thoroughly optimised, so there is nothing more to find out or improve.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86117/discussion-on-question-by-kkatja-a-word-or-a-phrase-for-completely-optimised-t).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most common term I have seen repeatedly and would thus use is, well established.

> **It is rather old, but [well-established](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-established) technology**

Note as correctly point out by @Chappo below in this case grammar dictates a hyphen is required since it is a compound adjective preceding a noun.

["science can be leading edge or well established"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology#Competitiveness) Wiki Technology

Comment: Note that since the expression is being used as an adjective, it's customary to hyphenate it: *well-established*.

Comment: @Chappo: I believe the most common convention is to hyphenate it in attributive position ("a well-established technology") but not in predicative position ("the technology is well established").

Comment: @ruakh yes, I agree. And there are already a number of questions on this site relating to whether to hyphenate in each case.

Comment: I would hesitate to use the phrase 'leading edge", as it seems ["cutting edge"]
(https://english.stackexchange.com/a/39919) is more popular everywhere but Australia, according to [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=leading%20edge,%22cutting%20edge%22,bleeding%20edge).

Comment: Also, while the phrase "well-established" is common generally, a term like "proven" or "tested" is much more common when talking about technology, according to [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=proven%20technology,well-established%20technology)

Answer (score 134):

I don't know of a technology that cannot be improved, but we often use the term ***mature*** to describe technology that's deemed developed enough to be left alone:

> A **[mature technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mature_technology)** is a technology that has been in use for long enough that most of its initial faults and inherent problems have been removed or reduced by further development. In some contexts, it may also refer to technology that has not seen widespread use, but whose scientific background is well understood.
>   *Wikipedia*

> **[mature](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mature)**
>   6. No longer subject to great expansion or development. Used of an industry, market, or product.
>   *American Heritage® Dictionary*

Comment: An illustrative quotation might help demonstrate the exact semantics of the term. Due to my hobbyist interests, I often hear that Cathode Ray Tubes were a mature technology. What do you think of adding something like "In the 1990s, C.R.T. television technology was a mature technology and new L.C.D. and plasma technologies were expected to displace C.R.Ts. rapidly." from 
[Turkey and the Global Economy: Neo-Liberal Restructuring and Integration in the Post-Crisis Era](https://books.google.com/books?id=KFiOAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT230&pg=PT230#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ziya Onis and Fikret Senses?

Comment: This is the answer. (Can't believe other terms are even being suggested for this.)

Comment: +1, though in the specific sentence the OP provided, I think "old, but mature" would be a bit awkward.

Answer (score 102):

You may be looking for ***proven***.

> It is rather old, but ***proven*** technology.

Collins:

> **[proven](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proven)** in British
>
> *adjective*
>   **3.**  tried; tested
>
> a proven method
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © Harper Collins Publishers
>
> **[proven](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proven)** in American
>
> *adjective*
>   **2.**  known to be valid, effective, or genuine
>
> a proven method
>
> Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition. Copyright © 2010
>   by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 48):

**tried and tested**

> adjective - recognized as reliable;  found to be successful
>
> tried-and-tested in British (ˈtraɪdəndˈtɛstɪd), tried-and-trusted
>   (ˈtraɪdəndˈtrʌstɪd) or US and Canadian **tried-and-true** (ˈtraɪdəndˈtruː)
>   adjective recognized as reliable; found to be successful
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tried-and-tested

As noted the expression varies somewhat according to location. All of the above versions would be understandable to a British person.

Comment: Does "state of the art" work?

Comment: No because the OP stated that it is 'old technology'.  State of the art only applies to the newest developments.

Comment: I would recommend changing the headline to tried and true, or *maybe* tried and trusted, while specifying which entry you checked within the quotation. Tried and tested just seems entirely redundant, and seems to skip over the "completely optimized" sentiment in favor of placing extra emphasis on the thorough research, so it doesn't seem like as good of a suggestion to place first as the others.

Comment: this does not look technical, at least in the computer science way

Comment: I did not know that "tried and tested" is British while American speakers say "tried and true". Another language/dialect difference to add in my blue book. @Tonepoet I don't find the former redundant whatsoever, you can try something out without doing any tests on it previously.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree with the assertion of your last clause, but I also stand by my statement. Try is often used in the context of testing and a test is almost always a kind of trying. The semantic overlap is especially evident in context. To draw a parallel, consider the sentence "My pet is a cat and an animal." The word animal has a meaning that's distinct from both pet and cat, but it is superfluous in context, since the sentiment is adequately expressed by those words. This is the less important factor though: Do you disagree with me that the "completely optimized" sentiment is less evident?

Comment: @Tonepoet you claimed the expression was *…entirely redundant, and seems to skip over the "completely optimized"* I disagreed, and I explained why. For instance, I can try out a new recipe, and find its results are satisfactory.  The next time I might change the dosage of something,  but find the results to be less than ideal. I may then experiment (test) further with different cooking times, and modify ingredients and doses until I find that perfect formula, the one that guarantees perfect results each and every time.

Answer (score 20):

### perfected

As an adjective, "perfect" describes a thing as *having* the qualities you're looking for; as a verb, it refers to *the activity or process of giving* it those qualities.

So as the past-tense of that verb, "perfected" says not just that a thing *is* in a state of perfection, but that it has been *brought* to this state -- with the connotation that it got there as the result of a rigorous, painstaking, iterative process, as opposed to a single act. Thus:

> It is rather old, but **perfected**, technology.

Ref:
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perfected

**perfect** [ *adjective, noun* **pur**-fikt; *verb* per-**fekt** ]

[...]

*verb (used with object)*

- to bring to completion; finish.
- to bring to perfection; make flawless or faultless:
  *He has succeeded in perfecting his recipe for chicken Kiev.*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This is on its way to being an excellent answer, but it's lacking one element: supporting evidence. An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. a dictionary definition for *perfected*) hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Good suggestion, but the sentence seems rather stilted. Maybe something like: "This technology is ancient, but has been perfected in the ..." could help?

Answer (score 12):

All of these answers, mature, well established, proven are absolutely correct in my opinion, but have become euphemisms for "out dated".  Whenever someone tries to sell me "mature" technology, I immediately think "barely usable in today's environment".

I would then describe this as [stable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stable):

> Not likely to change or fail
>   ; firmly established

or [fit for purpose](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fit_for_purpose):

> well equipped or well suited for its designated role or purpose

Comment: The sentence does start with `It is rather old`.

Comment: +1 for stable. It properly connotes that the technology has little need to change over time.

Answer (score 12):

The word that first came to mind for me was ***robust***, which a previous poster had used in describing the meaning of the word they were suggesting ("foolproof").

> [**robust**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robust)
>
> 1d : capable of performing without failure under a wide range of
>   conditions
>
> - *robust software*

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to EL&U. This was two elements short of being an excellent answer. It had an introductory explanation, the proposed solution is useful, it was supported by a dictionary definition of the key word, and you cited your source. All that was missing was a link to the online source (preferable but not mandatory), and some formatting to improve the appearance (helps attract additional upvotes!), both of which I've added. I look forward to your future contributions - and don't forget to take the **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 11):

I would offer **battle-tested**

Often used figuratively to imply its been used hard and been put through its paces and hardships - yet still remained viable.

[Battle tested](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/battle-tested)

As the dictionary example:

> —often used figuratively
>   The Yankees' pen, moreover, is battle-tested. Rivera, and his setup men, lefty Mike Stanton and righties Jeff Nelson and Ramiro Mendoza, have a combined 1.45 ERA over 105 2/3 innings of postseason experience.
>   — Tom Verducci, Sports Illustrated, 20 Sept. 1999

For your example:

> It is rather old, but **battle-tested** technology.

This would give the impression that the software has been put through its paces under considerable duress, unexpected uses and intense situations - and each time, came out still working!

Answer (score 7):

The technology has been *vetted*, formed from *vet* as a verb:

> **vet**: to subject to usually expert appraisal or correction ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vet#dictionary-entry-3))

Comment: In my experience in the software industry, this is what we say.  "This technology has been thoroughly vetted."

Comment: If something is vetted (even thoroughly) that doesn't in any way connote that there are no further improvements to be made to it... though the same is true of most answers given thus far.

Comment: Michael, it looks like you've copied your definition from MW. If you quote someone else's words, it's essential that you acknowledge the source. Not doing so is usually regarded as dishonest, in that you're passing off someone else's work as your own. More seriously, *plagiarism* is not tolerated on our site. I urge you to [edit] your post accordingly - look at the other answers for examples of how sources are embedded in links. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In the same vein as the good *tried and true* or *mature* is [**seasoned.**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seasoned) The Merriam-Webster entry gives "to make fit by experience" as one of the meanings of the  transitive verb. It is used in expressions like *seasoned advice* or *seasoned veterans* or *seasoned strategic planning consultants*.

I think *seasoned* implies that something or somebody functions *properly*, without fault. This likely includes sufficient efficiency but does not necessarily mean strictly *optimally,* so it's only a partial fit.

But it fits your word search nicely nevertheless because it already encompasses the "rather old" aspect. You can simply omit the "It is rather old" and say "It is a seasoned technology."

Answer (score 1):

I like *mature* or *proven*, but consider ***refined***:

> It is rather old, but ***refined*** technology.

I believe it gives a stronger connotation of something that was actively improved over time.

> **1.2** Developed or improved so as to be precise or subtle.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refined)</sub>

The strength of a *mature* or *proven* technology is the implication that it has been in use for a long time with few faults. It doesn't necessarily mean that it has been actively improved over time.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Clarification for everyone's imagination

Imagine a server software package that has a very robust toolbox of features and functions, but ***one very specific function*** in that toolbox that is used for a business critical process has a ***100% successful result always*** without ever having one hiccup.

### 2. What you ask. . .

In terms of what is asked word for word and per my interpretation of those words...

> "***address a technology that is totally investigated, researched in
>   detail, and thoroughly optimised, so there is nothing more to find out
>   or improve.***"

### 3. Features need love too. . .

Well this [technology] feature on this specific [technology] product has a specific [technology] function which has a 100% success rate for all results.

This technology (to me) which I speak of right here is [immaculate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immaculate) and [flawless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flawless) so using words to describe it as such seems both appropriate and reasonable.

So to say some [technology] feature or function of some software package works flawlessly just because that's what you experience with it gives exactly what is being asked of "technology".

### 4. Original Recipe (before pacification)

I'm thinking perhaps [flawless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flawless) may suit the need.

> It is rather old, but 
>   ***flawless***
>   technology.

- > [flawless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flawless)
  >   adjective
  >
  > `flaw·​less | \ˈflȯ-ləs  \`
  >
  > **Definition of flawless**
  >
  > 1 : having no flaw or imperfection : PERFECT

---

Otherwise consider [immaculate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immaculate) if you prefer it instead.

> It is rather old, but 
>   ***immaculate***
>   technology.

- > [immaculate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immaculate)
  >   adjective
  >
  > `im·​mac·​u·​late | \i-ˈma-kyə-lət  \`
  >
  > **Definition of immaculate**
  >
  > 2 : having or containing no flaw or error

Comment: Immaculate is more often associated with cleanliness than correctness. Also, there are few examples of technology which may be considered flawless, and none which incorporate software.

Comment: @sethrin Perhaps so but I imagine the software and the technology of it—like a feature or function of it—and how immaculate or flawless it works giving a consistent **positive result 100% of the time in someone's experience**.  I'm talking in terms of the "*address of a technology*" being the praising of specific features or functions and perfect results always. That software works flawlessly for processing 834 EDI files for example; I've never had any data issues post import to the database table using this software and it's "X" import functionality, it is flawless. Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Oh.... and the immaculate "X" import functionality I speak of, it is 100% ***totally investigated, researched in detail, and thoroughly optimized, so there is nothing more to find out or improve*** with it for that particular job I use it for which I speak of. It can be quite the robust software and in this particular instance, I speak of only that specific functionality, it is flawless!!! It's like Frank's Red Hot sauce too, I put that $&^% on everything!!!!

Comment: You would have a stronger case if you talked about correctness proofs of software. Your definition of "flawless" code is wholly inadequate, and vacuous.

Comment: Again, I'm not talking code or software specifically but the result that some [code] functionality, and thus that's how [the technology used] is perceived by people that use it routinely which makes perfect sense. I think you are simply over-analyzing it with a vague mindset just to make yourself feel like you are correct about something. It's all about context and interpretation so when a statement is vague with specificity, it can be looked at from different angles. Go Sethrin, it's birthday, go Sethrin, expand-your-mind day.

Comment: this is vacuous sophistry.

Comment: Yes, your argument is fatuous, I agree!!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the adjective [**fully fledged**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fully-fledged):

> **Fully fledged** means complete or fully developed.

This adjective comes from the idea that when a young bird has acquired its adult feathers, it is able to fly.

So, the OP's original example sentence is going to look like this:

> It is rather old, but **fully-fledged** technology.

Answer (score -1):

> [**unbeatable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unbeatable)
>
> *adjective* UK /ʌnˈbiː.tə.bəl/, US /ʌnˈbiː.t̬ə.bəl/.
>   **Unable to be defeated or improved because of excellent quality.**

Comment: Hi kervich, I've edited your post to add formatting and a hyperlink to the dictionary definition. Your post was ok, but these extra elements are desirable in a good answer and will help attract upvotes. To further improve your post, you can [edit] it to add your own explanation of why you think this is the best solution (be assertive!) and include some example sentences. NB: If you use an example from Cambridge, be sure to add it within the "blockquote" formatting, so that the source is clear. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Nobody so far has suggested **commodity** (noun) / **commoditised** (verb). Where something is so well-understood that anyone can make a new one cheaply, that won't be any better than the other options.

I work in the development of new technology and we often refer to things that aren't interesting to us any more as having been commoditised.

The Merriam Webster [definition of commodity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commodity) covers it under heading 3:

> 3: a good or service whose wide availability typically leads to smaller
>   profit margins and diminishes the importance of factors (such as brand
>   name) other than price

Answer (score -2):

In a technical context, you want [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understood) of the word **understood**, which carries more weight than the way it is used colloquially:

### *un·​der·​stood | \ˌən-dər-ˈstu̇d*

#### adjective

1. fully apprehended

The reason is *understood* is meant to be complete.  If it is 100%, totally investigated, researched into detail, thoroughly optimised so there is nothing more to find out or improve, in science it is referred to as *understood*.  Examples include:

> These are all interesting mathematical properties that are relevant to the description of physical systems, but they cannot be used as a catch-all, by saying that eventually all (un-**understood**) physical systems will be **understood** in terms of non-linearity.

*[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=tbqfAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=%22understood%22%20physical%20systems)*

And

> On the other hand, it has been found that many effects occuring in natural and man-made system of propagating waves can be best characterized and **understood** as parametric interactions of waves.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=DRQjAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA777&lpg=PA777&dq=%22understood%22)

In both the these examples, the *understood* concept is a fully studied one that can be safely used as a building block for more complicated models because there is nothing more to learn about it.

Answer (score -3):

**Streamlined** may fit your needs.

> It is rather old, but *streamlined* technology.

adjective - designed or organized to give maximum efficiency; compact.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/streamlined

I somewhat prefer this since it doesn't speak to the "newness" of the technology but it does imply that it is optimized or researched/planned in detail.

Answer (score -3):

The phrase that comes to mind immediately for me is a **well oiled machine**.

Macmillan dictionary [notes](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/well-oiled) that the adjective phrase describes something that "operates without problems;" Merriam-Webster [uses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-oiled) the defining phrase "smoothly functioning."

> The word or the phrase should address a technology, which is totally investigated, researched into detail, thoroughly optimised so there is nothing more to find out or improve.

"Well-oiled" indicates that everything is running optimally with no clear room for improvement and no implied efforts toward further investigation or research, but rather continuing with the great status quo.  Also, with more and more machines going digital, use of this phrase would cause a mental association with older technology, but technology that is still functioning well.

Answer (score -4):

I think the current top two answers are probably the ones I'd use. However, depending on your context you may prefer the term **exhaustive**.

> It is rather old, but *exhaustive* technology.

You might have the modify the sentence to add more context for it to make sense since the word *exhaustive* rarely stands on its own, but to me it conveys the idea that the technology has covered all the bases, so to speak. They've thought of everything.

Comment: As you say, the term does not work on its own in this context.

Answer (score -6):

There is a common acronym for this, used in computing and engineering, which is

**COTS** - "commercial off-the-shelf" - i.e. you can buy it ready made without having to do any research to invent it yourself, and without needing to understand every detail of how it works.

> It is rather old, but COTS technology.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/COTS

Comment: This doesn’t address the matter of how good or how well-researched the technology is.